# Why does the exec redirection disturb / interrupt a pipe to jq?

Tags: bash, jq, exec, tee

This is the reduced version of my script:

```
# parse json
echo '[{"foo":"bar"}]' | jq

# log output to file and stdout
exec &> >(tee -a "/tmp/test.log")

# parse json
echo '[{"foo":"bar"}]' | jq
```

Output:

```
# test.sh
[
  {
    "foo": "bar"
  }
]
jq - commandline JSON processor [version 1.5]
Usage: jq [options] <jq filter> [file...]

        jq is a tool for processing JSON inputs, applying the
...
```

So it seems the pipe to `jq` is gone lost, while `jq` is executed alone, but only after a redirection is active?! As I never faced a similar problem with other commands I'm really confused what is happening here.

Comment: Can't reproduce with bash 5.1.16 and jq 1.6 (although jq doesn't show color the second time, because it considers stdout to be not a tty).

Comment: Hmm ok. Maybe a bug in jq 1.5 (which I'm not able to update at the moment).

Comment: Maybe this one: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1110

Comment: That makes sense. If switching `jq` to `jq .` fixes your problem then I recommend that you write a self-answer saying so and pointing to the bug :)

Comment: Or this one: https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/1028

Comment: Someone marked the question as duplicate. Sady it does not explain why it happens in the `exec` case, but at least it contains the same solution to bypass the problem.

Comment: @mgutt It is _exactly_ the same reason as in the duplicate question, i.e., the output from `jq` is redirected due to the preceding `exec`, and with release 1.5 of the utility, this requires an explicit filter expression, which you don't provide.